# Dataset Preparation for Caffe

Tags: python, caffe, lmdb

I am new to machine learning and preparing a model for face detection by using caffe framework.
I have created my datdase, sorted it. I have created train.txt and val.txt whith ternary classification and image class also moved the pictures accordingly in the respective repository.

Now when I am preparing the database for training I am not able to successfully convert lmdb folders. I always run in to a problem.

First I thought my be my paths are not correct but I tried every thing but still run in to error. Here are the pictures of error and code.

Can someone please help me solve this problem.

I run the following script to creat lmdb (sh examples/FaceDetection/create_lmdb.sh)

```
    #!/usr/bin/env sh
    # Create the imagenet lmdb inputs
    # N.B. set the path to the imagenet train + val data dirs

    EXAMPLE=/home/hashim/caffe/examples/imagenet

    DATA=/home/hashim/Desktop/IVP/Face_6k

    TOOLS=build/tools

    TRAIN_DATA_ROOT=/home/hashim/Desktop/IVP/Face_6k

    VAL_DATA_ROOT=/home/hashim/Desktop/IVP/Face_6k

    # Set RESIZE=true to resize the images to 256x256. Leave as false if images have
    # already been resized using another tool.

    RESIZE=false

    if $RESIZE; then

      RESIZE_HEIGHT=256

      RESIZE_WIDTH=256

    else

      RESIZE_HEIGHT=0

      RESIZE_WIDTH=0

    fi



    if [ ! -d "$TRAIN_DATA_ROOT" ]; then

      echo "Error: TRAIN_DATA_ROOT is not a path to a directory: $TRAIN_DATA_ROOT"

      echo "Set the TRAIN_DATA_ROOT variable in create_imagenet.sh to the path" \

           "where the ImageNet training data is stored."

      exit 1

    fi



    if [ ! -d "$VAL_DATA_ROOT" ]; then

      echo "Error: VAL_DATA_ROOT is not a path to a directory: $VAL_DATA_ROOT"

      echo "Set the VAL_DATA_ROOT variable in create_imagenet.sh to the path" \

           "where the ImageNet validation data is stored."

      exit 1

    fi



    echo "Creating train lmdb..."



    GLOG_logtostderr=1 $TOOLS/convert_imageset \

        --resize_height=$RESIZE_HEIGHT \

        --resize_width=$RESIZE_WIDTH \

        --shuffle \

        $TRAIN_DATA_ROOT \

        $DATA/train.txt \

        $EXAMPLE/ilsvrc12_train_lmdb



    echo "Creating val lmdb..."



    GLOG_logtostderr=1 $TOOLS/convert_imageset \

        --resize_height=$RESIZE_HEIGHT \

        --resize_width=$RESIZE_WIDTH \

        --shuffle \

        $VAL_DATA_ROOT \

        $DATA/val.txt \

        $EXAMPLE/ilsvrc12_val_lmdb



    echo "Done."
```

and I get the following output:

Creating train lmdb...

```
    I1226 10:25:36.794904  3324 convert_imageset.cpp:86] Shuffling data

    I1226 10:25:36.795342  3324 convert_imageset.cpp:89] A total of 3602 images.

    F1226 10:25:36.796409  3324 db_lmdb.cpp:13] Check failed: mkdir(source.c_str(), 0744) == 0 (-1 
    vs. 0) mkdir /home/hashim/caffe/examples/imagenet/ilsvrc12_train_lmdb failed

    *** Check failure stack trace: ***

        @     0x7fe6b4bf20cd  google::LogMessage::Fail()

        @     0x7fe6b4bf3f33  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()

        @     0x7fe6b4bf1c28  google::LogMessage::Flush()

        @     0x7fe6b4bf4999  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()

        @     0x7fe6b4febbe8  caffe::db::LMDB::Open()

        @     0x558490bb05e9  (unknown)

        @     0x7fe6b39f2b97  __libc_start_main

        @     0x558490bb186a  (unknown)

    Aborted (core dumped)



    Creating val lmdb...

    I1226 10:25:36.966315  3334 convert_imageset.cpp:86] Shuffling data

    I1226 10:25:36.966552  3334 convert_imageset.cpp:89] A total of 1197 images.

    F1226 10:25:36.966617  3334 db_lmdb.cpp:13] Check failed: mkdir(source.c_str(), 0744) == 0 (-1 vs. 0) mkdir /home/hashim/caffe/examples/imagenet/ilsvrc12_val_lmdb failed

    *** Check failure stack trace: ***

        @     0x7f999df730cd  google::LogMessage::Fail()

        @     0x7f999df74f33  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()

        @     0x7f999df72c28  google::LogMessage::Flush()

        @     0x7f999df75999  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()

        @     0x7f999e36cbe8  caffe::db::LMDB::Open()

        @     0x5614b3ed95e9  (unknown)

        @     0x7f999cd73b97  __libc_start_main

        @     0x5614b3eda86a  (unknown)

    Aborted (core dumped)

    Done.
```

Please help me solve this problem.Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to run your script with admin privilages? something like chmod 777

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your program is trying to create a directory `/home/hashim/caffe/examples/imagenet/ilsvrc12_train_lmdb` but it is failing. I would recommend checking the following:

- Do all of the parent directories in the path leading up to `ilsvrc12_train_lmdb` exist?
- If the parent directories exist, does the user account that runs the script have the right permissions on all of the parent directories? Are the permissions sufficient to allow that user to create this directory?
- Have you tried manually creating the directory before running the program? You can use the `-p` flag to the `mkdir` command to create any missing intermediate directories:

```
mkdir -p /home/hashim/caffe/examples/imagenet/ilsvrc12_train_lmdb
```

- Did you try setting `EXAMPLE` to a different directory?

Most likely it's permission issues, though.

Comment: I have tried it all but still getting the same error. The program create the ilsvrc12_train_lmdb directory but is not converting the images to lmdb format. I guess its because I dont have enough memory???

Comment: So if you were to run `rm -rf /home/hashim/caffe/examples/imagenet/ilsvrc12_train_lmdb` and then run that script, you get the same error output you posted, and that directory will be recreated afterward? Because the relevant part of the error message is `Check failed: mkdir(source.c_str(), 0744) == 0 (-1 vs. 0) mkdir /home/hashim/caffe/examples/imagenet/ilsvrc12_train_lmdb failed` which tells me  that the directory was not created successfully. If the directory really is created, what is the output from `ls -ld /home/hashim/caffe/examples/imagenet/ilsvrc12_train_lmdb` ??